# How do I set up static serving in Express with an arbitrary start path?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

If I want to set up the directory `.../whatever/stuff` to be served statically, but referenced as `http://example.com/mystuff`, I tried doing this:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use('/mystuff', _express.static(__dirname + "/whatever/stuff"));
    app.use('/mystuff', _express.directory(__dirname + "/whatever/stuff"));
});
```

This *mostly* works, but if I reference a subdirectory of mystuff without a trailing slash, say `http://example.com/mystuff/subdir`, it redirects to the wrong place (`http://example.com/subdir/`), resulting in a 404.  This is especially problematic with directory listings, since the directory middleware doesn't put a trailing slash on links to subdirectories.

Is there something I can do to get around this?  (and is my syntax above correct?)

Comment: looks like a connect issue. you should create a small test scenario and file a bug at https://github.com/senchalabs/connect

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
app.use('/mystuff*', ..);
```