# how can I modify or replace the directory index page in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In express, I can something like this to have a static server, with directory index pages:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use('/mystuff', _express.static(__dirname + "/whatever/stuff"));
    app.use('/mystuff', _express.directory(__dirname + "/whatever/stuff"));
});
```

I would like to modify the directory index pages, by giving them different css, adding some javascript, and maybe altering the html.  I prefer use as much of the existing functionality if possible, but if it is easy to just replace the whole directory middleware with my own code, that's an option.  Not sure where to start with this.  Of course, I don't want to actually edit code in the express or connect modules.

BTW, one reason for this is to workaround a bug I mentioned here: [How do I set up static serving in Express with an arbitrary start path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808295/how-do-i-set-up-static-serving-in-express-with-an-arbitrary-start-path)

Comment: On what basis would you decide to use 'different css, js, html'?  Do you mean different per static page?  Different per visitor?  Different per ...??

Comment: I am not talking about static pages, I am talking about the directory index pages, the ones you go to if you don't have an index.html and you give a url to a directory.Those pages have whatever javascript and css the developer of Express and Connect put in there.  I just want to link to  my own file, or put some js and css into the generated html.  It would be exactly the same on all directory index pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in your comment, the `express.directory` functionality comes from [Connect middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/directory.html); however, there doesn't seem to be a way to set a custom file.

As an alternative solution, you could fork Connect, change the files (located at `lib/public/directory.html` and `lib/public/style.css`), use your fork as a dependency, and do:

```
var connect = require('connect');

app.configure(function() {
    app.use('/mystuff', connect.static(__dirname + "/whatever/stuff"));
    app.use('/mystuff', connect.directory(__dirname + "/whatever/stuff"));
});
```

Instead of the express ones.  I just tested this (by editing the files in node_module), and it worked.

**EDIT:**
Actually, you could probably just grab `directory.js` from connect and modify it and put it in your app and `require()` it, and then use yours instead.  I haven't tested this, but I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks.  Since all I really had to do was add a couple lines to the directory.html file (to link to css and javascript files), there wasn't much reason for fork anything for now.  It's a shame that's not easier to customize without hacking the module.

Comment: You'd probably be better off finding a non-hack way to deal with it, or npm may overwrite your changes.  I just made an edit with an alternative.  I haven't tested it yet, but it should work.